# Need a Control with Editing Template

Tags: wpf, listview, custom-controls

I am working on a custom grid like control inheriting from ListView.
I want each cell of this control to have 2 modes, Editing mode and normal mode, based on which i will switch between DefaultTemplate and EditingTemplate.

I tried using DataGridCell inside the ListView and applying trigger on its IsEditing property to switch between my templates. But did not work..

I may have to create a custom control to achieve this. If so, please suggest how to capture the editing mode.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you considered to add  a bool property called IsEditMode to your object model and bind the switch of your data templates to this new property?

Comment: i have to perform this on user action, wondering which action to capture, double click?.. keyboard enter? escape key? lost focus?... Should i even have to create a custom control or are there any existing control which can give me this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I do this with a DataGrid and RowDetails

[DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate.aspx)